# move application to another screen in i3mw

Tags: i3

I would like to move focused application to newly created screen.
Screen would be automatically created when shortcut (for moving application) is pressed.

The screen name should be the name of the application.

Typical use case for this would be when I open another application, this app is tiled on my existing screen. I would like to de-clutter the screen by moving the application to another screen, but new screen name should be something meaningful.

So far I managed to create new screen, and name it generically, by modifying a script from the net.
Then I move focused application to that screen like so:

In my config file is the binding:

```
bindsym $mod+n exec --no-startup-id ".config/i3/scripts/move_container.sh"
```

the script move_container.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_SCREEN_NUM=`/usr/bin/i3-msg -t get_workspaces | tr , '\n' | grep '"num":' | cut -d : -f 2 | sort -rn | head -1`

NEXT_SCREEN_NUM=$((CURRENT_SCREEN_NUM + 1))

/usr/bin/i3-msg move container to workspace $NEXT_SCREEN_NUM
/usr/bin/i3-msg workspace $NEXT_SCREEN_NUM
```

however, this leaves me with the screen labelled by a number, and I would like a more descriptive name.
So I am looking for application name or the like.

Comment: @roaima, I edited my question. Hope it helps.